# Indented vertical lines in list, (as seen in 99 Variations on a Proof by P. Ording)

Tags: lists, enumerate, itemize, framed, logic

I'd like to replicate this: [image]

I'm having trouble with the indented vertical line, everything else is just a list, I think. I tried a couple of `leftbar` and lists environments; but `leftbar` is not indented in any of them and I'm not sure how to fix it.

An example of an attempt to making it work and also how I'd like it to work:

```
\renewenvironment{leftbar}[1][\hsize]
{% 
    \def\FrameCommand 
    {%
        
        {\hspace{-3pt}\color{black}\vrule width 1.5pt}%
        \hspace{-43pt}%must no space.
    }%
    \MakeFramed{\hsize#1\advance\hsize-\width\FrameRestore}%
}
{\endMakeFramed}%

\begin{enumerate}[label=]
\item a
    \begin{leftbar}
       a\\
       b\\
       c\\
    \end{leftbar}
\item b 
\end{enumerate}
```

I tried nesting the `leftbar` environment inside `enumerate` and various variations of nesting. I tried many spacing comands (i.e. `\quad`) I also tried using `itemize` instead of `enumerate`. Also making the `leftbar` and `enumerate` environment items when they're nested inside another list environment. I tried the `aligned` environment but I think it's not what it's going to work. (the `renewenvironment` is not mine, I copy pasted it in thinking it may help).

This is how most of my output looks:

[image]

The source of the original picture is variation 18 of the book *99 Variations on a Proof* by Philip Ording.

Comment: You could put something like `\smash{\rule[-2\dp\strutbox]{0.4pt}{2\baselineskip}}` in a label (`\item`).  The `\smash` allows it to overlap above and below.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe this goes in the right direction.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newenvironment{leftbar}{\begin{array}{@{}p{1.5ex}@{}|@{}p{1.5ex}@{}l}
    &&\begin{aligned}[t]
        }{\end{aligned}
    \end{array}}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
    a&=b\\
    &\begin{leftbar}
        &=c \\
        &=d\\ 
        &\begin{leftbar}
            &=e \\
            &=f\\ 
        \end{leftbar}\\
        &=g
    \end{leftbar}\\
    &=h
\end{align*}   
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your response, this is very helpful. I don't have experience defining new environments and I'd like know how it works, As a beginner, would reading the `array` docs suffice? or do I need to know plain `TeX` first?

Comment: @Lisica This is just LaTeX (latex2e, to be more precise), see e.g. https://texdoc.org/serve/latex2e.pdf/0.